# How to return list item selected to parent activity - android

Tags: android, listview

I'm learning android development. And I trying to do the following:

An wellcome activity, with a TextView with the following text: "Please Select"

This Textview, has an OnClick Listener setted.

My intent is, when the user click on this textview, one new activity with a listview must be opened.

This listview cointains some values like: Country 1, Country 2, Country 3 and so on;

So, when the user select one value, this value must be returned to the parent activity.

In my parent activity I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    countrySamples = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countrySamples);
    countrySamples.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListCountrySelectedFragment whatKindOjectIsThis = new ListCountrySelectedFragment();
            whatKindOjectIsThis.setListCountrySelectedActivityDelegate(new ListCountrySelectedFragment.ListCountrySelectedActivityDelegate() {
                @Override
                public void selectCountry(String name) {
                    selectItem(name);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

[...]

```
    public void selectItem(String name) {
    int index = valuesArray.indexOf(name);
    if (index != -1) {
        countryButton.setText(name);
    }
}
```

And I've created an blank fragment with a list.

And added the following code:

```
public static interface ListCountrySelectedActivityDelegate {
    public abstract void selectCountry(String name);
}

private ListCountrySelectedActivityDelegate delegate;
```

[...]

But, my fragment is never started.. The true is.. I have to create a Fragment to this? Or, must by an activity? Or I'm totally wrong?

Thanks

**Edited (complete code):**

Login Activity:

```
package com.testenum_13;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.testenum_13.R;
import com.testenum_13.adapters.CountryAdapter;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView countryButton;

    private EditText codeField;

    private int countryState = 0;

    private ArrayList<String> countriesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HashMap<String, String> countriesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private boolean ignoreOnTextChange = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        countryButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countryButton);
        countryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, CountrySelected.class);
                CountrySelected fragment = new CountrySelected();
                fragment.setCountrySelectActivityDelegate (new CountrySelected.CountrySelectActivityDelegate() {
                    @Override
                    public void countryWSelected(String name) {
                        selectCountry(name);
                    }
                });
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void selectCountry(String name) {
        int index = countriesArray.indexOf(name);
        if (index != -1) {
            ignoreOnTextChange = true;
            codeField.setText(countriesMap.get(name));
            countryButton.setText(name);
            countryState = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Country Activity:

```
package com.testenum_13;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.testenum_13.adapters.CountryAdapter;
import com.testenum_13.adapters.CountryAdapter.Country;

import java.util.List;


public class CountrySelected extends FragmentActivity {
    public static interface CountrySelectActivityDelegate {
        public abstract void countryWSelected(String name);
    }
    private CountryAdapter listViewAdapter;
    private CountrySelectActivityDelegate delegate;

    ListView countryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_country_selected);

        countryList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.countryList);

        listViewAdapter = new CountryAdapter(getBaseContext());

        countryList.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        countryList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Country country = null;

                int section = listViewAdapter.getSectionForPosition(position);
                int row = listViewAdapter.getPositionInSectionForPosition(position);
                if (row < 0 || section < 0) {
                    return;
                }
                country = listViewAdapter.getItem(section, row);
                if (position < 0) {
                    return;
                }
                if (country != null && delegate != null)
                {
                    delegate.countryWSelected(country.name);
                }
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void setCountrySelectActivityDelegate(CountrySelectActivityDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_country_selected, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: where the listview is present? i mean in activity or fragment?

Comment: the listview was added into the child fragment...

Comment: can you show your total code?

Comment: The code was posted... and I transformed the fragment into an second activity.. I'm totally lost..

Comment: you want to get the data from send activity to starting activity right?

Comment: Right, but the CountrySelected activity is not started with:
CountrySelected fragment = new CountrySelected();
                fragment.setCountrySelectActivityDelegate (new CountrySelected.CountrySelectActivityDelegate()[...]

Answer (score -1):

You could use `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` in the parent Activity and override `onActivityResult()` in the child activity. See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) tutorial for more details on how to implent this pattern.